# Reputation for tags has been stuck for 3 days on SO

Tags: bug, tag-score

Since other threads I've read here ask to wait at least 3 days for the reputation update on a specific tag, I waited three days until 5:00 UTC but saw no change in any of my tags on stackoverflow.

Is the process delegated to do this stuck or is there something I didn't consider?

Comment: This is a [wildly recurring issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+tag-score) that still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Thanks animuson, I must have missed that one. I didn't imagine this issue was so consistent.

Comment: Reported on MSO here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272647/why-does-the-vote-count-on-my-profiles-tags-not-update. It has been considerably more than 3 days. I don't remember when exactly it started, but I believe we're approaching a week since the last update.